# How to print specified lines to a new file in shell?

Tags: shell

How to get the specified rows by row numbers to a new file by shell?
for example, there are 1000 lines in original file, I just want to get the No. 40~60 line to a new file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sed` line number address and `p` command.

```
sed -n '40,60p' a.txt > b.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you may try to use `awk`,

```
awk '(NR>=40 && NR<=60){print}' file1 > file2
```

Comment: No reason you can't use `awk`, but is more often seen with `sed`. Good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `head` and `tail`

```
head -n 60 file | tail -n 20
```

The last 20 lines of 60 first